# Riemann sum, Thomae function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[1, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }x \not\in \mathbb{Q} \\
\frac1q, & \text{if }x = \frac{p}{q}, \text{$p$ and $q$ coprime}
\end{cases}
$$

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ be the points where $f(x) \geq \varepsilon$.  Let $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{\max\{f(a_i)\}}$ and consider a partition $P[1, 2]$ such that $\|P\| < \delta$.  Show that $S(f, P, \{c_i\}) < \varepsilon$.

(Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeSDg.png)

I started considering $A=\left\{x \mid x=\frac{p}{q},f(x) \geq \varepsilon        \right\}$, I showed that there are infinitely many terms in $A$, and I use that to construct the intervals. I don't know if this lead to somewhere, I completely lost, can somebody help?

Comment: OP: I've rendered the inlined image as MathJax.  Please check that it faithfully (enough) reproduces the content of the image.

Comment: I'm not sure what the $c_i$ refer to.  Do you mean the $a_i$?

Comment: note that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is only a finite number of rationals $p/q \in [1,2]$ such that $1/q\geq \varepsilon$, so the set $A$ cannot be infinite.

Comment: is the tagged partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm going to make some assumptions here, feel free to correct me if they're wrong.

$\textbf{Assumptions:}$
I assume you're trying to show that
$$\int_1^2f=0$$

I assume $P,\{c_i\}$ is a tagged partition. So we can write
$$P=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$$
where
$$1=x_0<x_1\ldots<x_r=2$$
and
$$c_i\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$$
I am also assuming that
$$S(s,P,\{c_i\})=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}f(c_i)|x_{i+1}-x_i|$$
Lastly, I assume that by $\|P\|<\delta$ you mean
$$|x_{i+1}-x_i|<\delta$$
for all $i$. Under these assumptions. Give these assumptions, I'll prove the Riemann Integral exists and equals 0.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

First WLOG we may assume $\delta<\epsilon/\sum_{i=1}^m f(a_i).$

Let $j_1,\ldots,j_k$ be all the $j$ such that $c_j=a_i$ for some $i$. Note that as $c_j$ are all distinct we have $k\leq m$. Then
$$S(f,P,\{c_i\})=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}f(c_i)|x_{i+1}-x_i|=\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\not=j_1,\ldots,j_k}}^{r-1}f(c_j)|x_{i+1}-x_i|+\sum_{i=1}^kf(c_j)|x_{i+1}-x_i|$$
$$\leq\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}\epsilon|x_{i-1}-x_i|+\sum_{i=1}^mf(a_i)\delta$$
$$\leq\epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^{m}f(a_i)\cdot\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sum_{i=1}^mf(a_i)}\right)\leq 2\epsilon$$

So for $\|P\|<\delta$ we find that $S(f,P,\{c_i\})<2\epsilon$, hence
$$\int_1^2f=0$$
as desired.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: One question. That choice of delta is the same as δ=ε/max{f(ai)}?

Comment: nevermind, i get it, thank you a lot!